# Array where there is a non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I was running my code, when I received the following error message:

"Error in t-1: non-numeric argument to binary operator"

The error is in p[t]<-p[t-1] in the function:

```
p<-rep(0, dimension)

price<-function(n, dimension){

  p[t]<-p[t-1]

...
}
```

this function is recalled into another function where p[t=0] is equal to 1. T represents the time at which an order is submitted. At the beginning, i.e. for t=0, p[t]<-1. I also tried to change p[t-1] into p[t] and p[t] into p[t+1], but it gives me the same error.
Could you please tell me how I can fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: the error is because `t` is a function in r. `t()` is used to transpose a matrix.. And you are trying to use it as an index without even defining it.. You need to define it

Comment: Thank you, Onyambu. Unfortunately also after changing t in tt I have the same error message

Comment: did you define what `tt` is??

Comment: r starts indexing from 1 and not from 0 like most other languages

Comment: You need to note the environment at which `tt` is defined. Acording to your example above, `tt` isnot defined anywhere.. If defined inside a function, it will just be confined to that function...

Comment: Thank you for your help, Onyamby. I defined tt into an init() function which I called at the beginning of my simulations (loop for). Then I used the price function, but tt it was not an argument of that function.

Comment: Then there is no way you can use it here since it is not defined here.. It is defined in a different environment. Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Onyambu. In the C code that I wrote, I used arrays and functions. I have tried to re-write it using R language, but I am having problems with arrays, specifically when I need to compute price[t+1]=price[t] in a trade function, after initialised price[0]=1 in an inititialisng function. How can I write these steps in R?